# How to update the Elastic Beanstalk Node.js project without erasing the files

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mean-stack, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I am trying to do some changes to my node project and redeploying it to elastic beanstalk, I am losing the previous uploaded image but the text contents remains same. My application is uploading image when it is on the server side. But once I upload a new version my all uploaded files got missing.

Please note that I have also added MongoDB client with the EC2 instance IP.

Comment: I think this is because you are storing the uploaded images on the ec2 instance attached to your beanstalk. You should store you images in s3 or some other place.

Comment: Cleaning up the text a bit